# ¿Cómo restar usando: Bar chart js?

Tags: chart.js

Tengo el siguiente código:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["2015-01", "2015-02"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Tomatoes',
      data: [12, 19],
      borderWidth: 1
    }, {
      label: '# of Tomatoes',
      data: [10, 19],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.4/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Esto me dibuja la primera barra y da como resultado **12 + 10 = 22**, pero ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que reste en vez de sumar?